# Stabilize pose estimation keypoints

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, kalman-filter

I'm currently facing a problem of stabilizing the generated key points from the HRNet as [in this repository](https://github.com/leoxiaobin/deep-high-resolution-net.pytorch).

I created my personalized dataset where the key points mark the extreme locations of an airplane: nose, tail and wings.

The problem is that the dataset marks *the actual furthest positions* and the prediction is always shifted a couple of pixels to the side.

**Question : Is there any algorithm that will stabilize the prediction so they don't shake too much between predictions?**

Objects move and I am trying to track their joints and make the movement smoother. Two options come to my mind:

- averaging predictions across iterations,
- Kalman filter.
  Any ideas how to improve the process?